# Spreadsheet VLOOKUP: Search in second column and return first

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

In Excel or OpenOffice calc I have

```
| Foo | Bar |
+-----+-----+
| A   | 1   |
| B   | 2   |
```

Is it possible to use `VLOOKUP` to search a value in the Bar column and return the value in the Foo column?

Comment: No it isn't, which is why Jook's answer doesn't use it. `VLOOKUP` can only use the left hand column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/645039/excel-vlookup-by-second-column-using-table-name-as-range

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(2,B:B,0),1)
```

This chooses a specific cell out of a matrix.

`MATCH` retrieves the row inside the matrix `B:B` where "2" was found with exact match (0).

`INDEX` uses this row, and a given column (1), to refer to a specific cell inside a matrix `A:B`.

"Foo" would be in column A, "Bar" would be column B.

Comment: +1 Also working in Google Sheets.