# Excel VLOOKUP by second column using table name as range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

Using the example table below, I can use the formula `=VLOOKUP("ABC123456",Table1,3,FALSE)` to lookup the `Demand` value, but I want to do be able to perform the lookup by using the `Cust Part` field without having to make the `Cust Part` field the first column in the table. Making `Cust Part` the first column isn't an acceptable solution, because I also need to perform lookups using the `Part` field, and I don't want to use hard coded ranges (e.g. `$B$2:$C$4`) mostly as a matter of preference, but also because using table and field names makes the formula easier to read. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible to use `OFFSET` to return the Table1 range but 1 column over, e.g.

`=VLOOKUP("AZ12345",OFFSET(Table1,0,1),2,FALSE)`

That will look up AZ12345 in the CustPart column and return the value from the next column

Comment: What parameter should be here if Part column value is needed here?

Answer (score 17):

You can combine `INDEX` and `MATCH` to acheive the same result of `VLOOKUP` without the comparison being restrained to the first column. Though it is slightly more complex.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Demand],MATCH("AZ12345",Table1[Cust Part],0))
```

Basically, you're using `MATCH` to find the row number, and `INDEX` to get the value.

*Note: Unlike `VLOOKUP`, if the result is a blank cell, `INDEX` will return `0` instead of a blank string.*

Comment: "Unlike `VLOOKUP`"? It behaves exactly the same way regarding blank cells being translated into 0s.

Comment: This is the first example I've seen with ```INDEX MATCH``` using a table.  This greatly improves readability of the formula.  I was trying to avoid ```OFFSET``` because it is a volatile Excel function and may result in extra overhead processing.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
=VLOOKUP("ABC123456";Table1[[Cust Part]:[Demand]];COLUMNS(Table1[[Cust Part]:[Demand]]);FALSE)
```

I prefer this so that you can see what you are doing, even in more complex tables, plus if the structure of the table changes, the formula will still work, as long as the Cust Part column is in front of the Demand column.

Answer (score 0):

This is cheating, but its a low-brow solution to the problem that I implemented many years ago before I learned about any of these other solutions.

What I did was created a fourth column on the right end, with the same contents as the first.

Then I did a simple VLOOKUP using the sub-table that began with the second column and ended with the fourth.  The code, therefore, is trivial.

Then you can hide the fourth column from view, if you wish.